# How to change xlabel in pandas matplotlib stacked bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The easiest way to plot a pandas dataframe is as described in the documentation like this:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

In my case I want to create a stacked bar chart:

```
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True);
```

This is all working well, but I would like to use one column of the df2 as xlabels and not simply have [1,2,3,4... etc] as labels. Is there a simple way to achieve it with an additional parameter in the plot function or do I need to do it in a more complicated way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot uses the index of your dataframe as the labels so if you want to your use use a particular column, set it as your index:

```
df2.index = df2.labelcol
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```